# The feed, which is posted to Facebook App Page using PHP, does not show up on the page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have an App Page, to which I can post feeds on the Facebook page manually. But when I do that from php code following the curl api nothing shows up on the feeds. No error message is gotten either. 
I have read and tried every single reply to similar questions on SOF. nothing worked for me.
Here is the latest code (
I have tried this logic in different implementations using a class, and not using a method for message etc):

```
        function message($data)
        {
            $page_id = 'xxxxxxxx';
            $data['access_token'] = 'xxxxxxxx';

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


            $return = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return $return;
        }


    message(array( 'message'  => 'message',
               'link'     => 'link',
               'picture'  => 'picture',
               'name'     => 'name',
               'description' => 'description') );                       
?>
```

Comment: You have debugged the access token? To make sure it is a page access token with the right permissions

Comment: The access token seems valid. And the page id is correct too.

Comment: It goes a little quicker if you answer the second question also. What permissions does it have?

Comment: @WizKid: Where can I set those permissions?

Comment: On https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I selected the page under "Page Access Tokens". Then looked at the access token Scopes: manage_pages, public_profile.